# How to insert current system date in oracle not the database date?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to insert my system date by using the query is,"insert into table values (current_date)",But it is inserting database date, Help me to solve this problem

Comment: in your comment on an answer below you write that you want to insert the value of the local (client) computer's system time. please include this information in the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

`CURRENT_DATE` returns the date/time in your current session time zone. Most likely you did not set the session time zone and Oracle defaults it to database time zone.

You can set your session time zone explicitly by

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = ...
```

Default `SESSIONTIMEZONE` can be set by environment variable `ORA_SDTZ` or (on Windows) by registry entry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\ORA_SDTZ` (for 32 bit Client), resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%\ORA_SDTZ` (for 64 bit Client).